# What is Meetup Everywhere for?

Tags: meetup

Meetup.com recently released [Meetup Everywhere](http://www.meetup.com/everywhere/).  It is a variation on their existing event listing and RSVP engine.  What is the key technological and social difference between meetup everywhere and a regular paid meetup group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meetup Groups (or just Meetup) are started by individuals to create a community about something in their town, while Meetup Everywhere is for organizations, companies, and movements to enable their fans/followers/customers/audience to create a community about them, everywhere.